# Apache Service Mix Deployment Approaches

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, apache-servicemix, bundles

Folks,

We have got an enterprise application which uses Apache Service Mix for deployment. The application consists of various services and each is created as separate Maven project (bundle).During development, we are actually building each service separately and in-order to deploy it,its being put in the deploy folder. Also, we have to uninstall the bundle from the container(say; karaf) and then install it again from the console to bring the new changes in effect. This is fine during the development phase.

Now we want to deploy the code to an UAT environment (Amazon EC2) for the client to do the testing. We are now confused about how to deploy the bundles to the remote environment. Do we have a standard approach for CI using Jenkins(or some other tool) to automate the build and deploy process , so that someone who has no knowledge about the bundles(SMX) can deploy the code. We are using Github for source code management.

We have searched a lot in this regard and couldn't find any resources which provide some leads/hints on this.

Any help/tips is highly appreciated. If you need more info, I can give more details.

~Ragesh

Answer (score 0):

We do have exactly similar setup and we use the Jenkins to build and let the Sysadmin to copy the bundles to one server and then he enables the rsync to rest of the servers.

Remember, always deploy the dependent bundle first and then remaining ..
Since we have this dependency ,we can't go automating this process.